# I want to give a user with minimum permissions the ability to use a content editor

Tags: development, content-editor-web-part

Just one particular content editor. So the user's permissions will still apply (i.e. they are not an editor so typically cannot edit) but will still have access to a content editor's rich editing features for one particular control.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question a little further. Its rather confusing in the current state.

Comment: Well this is a scenario were we'd probably typically use a 3rd party wysiwyg editor (ckeditor) for example - but want to use the SharePoint one. In a nutshell - how can I use content editor as a wysiwyg editor for users that are not even contributors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but you can use the RTE without the ribbon controls. We have a public facing site and didn't want to use the ribbon for general users.

http://blog.mastykarz.nl/rich-text-editor-control-sharepoint-2010/